# Unexpected Results From Postgresql Query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find a way to create a table where it shows each customer profile (71 in total) their top item bought per time frame (10 in total), what that item is, and the time frame that was most popular. Whenever I run this query it shows the top items for a time frame but it shows all the customers as null. I also need a way to display the customer name which is also accessed through the id_table. I'm lost so any direction would be greatly appreciated! I only have read permissions on this DB.

```
select distinct id_table.name as product_name, pb.recruitment_round, count(pb.purchased), st.cust_dbf_id as cust_profile
from   product_bought pb
join id_table
on id_table.dbf_id = pb.dbf_id 
left join shopper_table st
on st.cust_dbf_id = id_table.dbf_id 
where pb.date >= '2022-01-01'
and pb.date <= '2022-01-05'
and pb.shopping_time = 4
group by id_table."name", pb.recruitment_round, pb.cust_dbf_id 
order by count(pb.purchased) desc, pb.recruitment_round
limit 1;
```

Expected: a return of st.cust_dbf_id.
Received: Null values

Comment: Why do you think getting NULL for st.cust_dbf_id must be wrong?  That is the whole point of doing a LEFT join, isn't it?

Comment: A full join is doing the same thing and a right join is returning nothing. I'm fairly new to SQL. Could the problem be that st.cust_dbf_id is not flagged as a foreign or primary key?